# Honest and consistent magento 2 tutorial

Tags: magento2

Do you know any honest and consistent Magento 2 tutorial?

I tried already search different tutorial but I am not sure that are honest and consistent.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/aleron75/mageres

Comment: If it is useful then accept as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to personalty suggest you to read [Magento DevDocs Tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com)  but in devdocs there is not more explanation with example for the basic theory you need to read devdocs for the practical practices you need to read and practice with different bolg site so you can better understand.

Heare is a list of blog site.

1. [Mageplaza blog](https://www.mageplaza.com/)
2. [inchoo Blog](https://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/)
3. [Magestore](https://blog.magestore.com/)
4. [Alanstrom](https://alanstorm.com/category/magento/)
5. [Rakesh Jesadiya blog (Magento master)](http://rakeshjesadiya.com)

And finally all in one https://github.com/jaimin-ktpl/mageres

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I must suggest to read [Alan Storm](https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/) or [Inchoo's](https://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/) blog. They both have write about Magento2 in briefly. Also for some basic concepts to understand you should follow below two tutorials on youtube.

- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCU9_zxAnC0f51pSBBiPwJ1g/playlists?pbjreload=10
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQQUd8xe2EWU0k2TU0V_PSEiDpCzuF_OW

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I was searching blogs too, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are fresher in magento2

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/
https://webkul.com/blog/dev/
 links can help you for basic concepts

But if you want to understand all the concepts properly

no one document better than this

https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors

Comment: I am fresher user, thx for yours links

Answer (score 0):

Few of the below links can help you, Magento 2's official document is the best i feel, it is very neatly divided into various concepts and modules. Below are the few links that can help you:

https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/

https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/

Comment: ok thx, to this time I was using magestore

Answer (score 0):

In Addition with others answer,

You can refer this vinaikopp blog also. here you will find the blog series for creating module from scratch including every part:

http://vinaikopp.com/blog/list/4/